# Twilio - Get the most recent Conference call

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to find the fastest way to get a Conference Sid from an ended call's request. Since the Participant is removed from the Conference when the call ends, searching isn't possible (and not implemented in the PHP library anyways). I'm assuming the call left the most recent Conference, since its 'action' parameter is associated with its Dial into the Conference.

How do I get the most recent Conference using the PHP helper library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I don't think there is a way to just get the last conference directly from the API.  What you can do is use the helper library to get a list of the conferences.

```
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
foreach ($client->account->conferences as $conference) {
    print $conference->date_created;
}
```

When you do, each conference should include a DateCreated and a DateUpdated property that you can sort by to find the last one created or updated.

Hope that helps.